# CUDA Unified Memory and use of std::vector in device code

Tags: cuda

Back in the days, std::vector was not allowed in CUDA device code. Is that still true with current cuda 10.2 toolkit with Unified Memory?

I have a few public data members of type std::vector in a class that is passed reference to be used by a device kernel.

nvcc complains about calling a **host** function("std::vector...) ... from a **global** function("...) not allowed.

What is the correct way to use unified memory, if at all possible, to use on an std::vector? If it is not possible, is there an efficient work-around?

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#standard-library

Answer (score 1):

> Back in the days, `std::vector` was not allowed in CUDA device code. Is that still true with current cuda 10.2 toolkit with Unified Memory?

Yes.

> What is the correct way to use unified memory, if at all possible, to use on an `std::vector`?

There is not one. It isn't possible. [There is no C++ standard library support on the device](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#standard-library).

> If it is not possible, is there an efficient work-around?

No there is not.